# How to connect esp_mqtt library to thingsboard.io?

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, thingsboard

I am trying to publish sensor data using esp_mqtt library to thingsboard.io dashboard. But the connection between the library and thingsboard is not getting established. I am using esp8266 nodeMCU v2 and platformIO

Here is the link to the esp_mqtt library documentation.
https://github.com/tuanpmt/esp_mqtt/blob/master/README.md

Here is the code snippet :

```
    #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
    #include <MQTT.h>


    #define CLIENT_ID "client1"
    #define TOPIC "v1/devices/me/telemetry"
    #define TOKEN "access token"

    MQTT myMqtt(CLIENT_ID,"localhost",1883);
    const char* ssid     = "ssid";
    const char* password = "password";


    void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(1000);
    setup_wifi();
    Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT server");

    // setup callbacks
    myMqtt.onConnected(myConnectedCb);
    myMqtt.onDisconnected(myDisconnectedCb);
    myMqtt.onPublished(myPublishedCb);
    myMqtt.onData(myDataCb);

    Serial.println("connect mqtt...");
    myMqtt.setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
    myMqtt.setUserPwd(TOKEN,"");

    myMqtt.connect();
    Serial.println("subscribe to topic...");
    myMqtt.subscribe(TOPIC);
    delay(10);
    }


      void loop() {

     float value = analogRead(A0);
     String temp=String(value);

    // publish value to topic
     String payload = "{";
    //payload += "\"temperature\":"; payload += temperature; payload += ",";
     payload += "\"temperature\":"; payload += temp;
     payload += "}";

     // Send payload
     char attributes[100];
     payload.toCharArray( attributes, 100 );
     //String(attributes);
     boolean result = myMqtt.publish("v1/devices           
     /me/telemetry",attributes,100,1,0);
      delay(1000);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect to `localhost` unless you are running a broker on the ESP8266 this is never going to work.

You need to know what the host name of thingsboard.io's broker is and replace `localhost` with that value. The port number may also need changing.

I'm also guessing the clientid may need to be something a little more unique than `client1`

Comment: client id does not need to be unique in case of TB MQTT API. but the username should contain an access token.